# How to choose just a single row from a list of selections

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table as follows:

[image]

In the future the table will have several more rows.
I am trying to select `currentStage` from the database using the following code:

```
$currentStage = mysql_query("
SELECT `currentStage` FROM `team` WHERE `gameID` = '$gameID'
");
```

Using the above selects the two `1's` from the data base however I really just want to select one of them. With only the gameID as a reference. (ie. I can only use `WHERE`gameID`= '$gameID'` as a method of finding) Is there a way of doing this?

I hope this makes sense

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LIMIT 1` to fetch only one row from the result set:

```
SELECT `currentStage`
FROM `team`
WHERE `gameID` = '$gameID'
LIMIT 1
```

Alternatively you can use MIN or MAX to find the minimum or maximum value:

```
SELECT MIN(`currentStage`) AS `currentStage`
FROM `team`
WHERE `gameID` = '$gameID'
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks, I will look into this added functionality. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

JUST PUT the limit at last `limit 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
$currentStage = mysql_query("SELECT `currentStage` FROM `team` WHERE `gameID` = '$gameID' LIMIT 1");
```